# Regex to Limit email format - local part must contain dot

Tags: regex, email

I'm trying to lightly validate an email address and I'm almost there but I can't figure out how to force the local part to include a dot.

The general format that should pass the validation is :

```
firstname.lastname@subdom.domain.com
```

where the local part must contain a dot or more than one dot, but not consecutively.  The dot cannot start the email.
Apostrophes and hyphens  are ok but not as beginning characters.

`name@subdom.domain.com` must fail.

This is what I have, but its still validating  `name@subdom.domain.com`

```
^(\w+)([\-.'][\w]+)*@(\w[\-\w]*\.){1,3}([A-Za-z]){2,6}
```

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. The suggested duplicate is about an issue with subdomains and dots,  subdomains work properly in this regex.  This is about the local part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the `*` with  a `+`

i.e. 0 or more with 1 or more

```
^(\w+)([\-.'][\w]+)*@(\w[\-\w]*\.){1,3}([A-Za-z]){2,6}
                   |
                  here
```